# String in string, get inside string

Tags: python-3.x

The original List is this

```
a=['="1111"', '="2222"', '="3333"', '="4444"']
```

I try this

```
b=[b.strip('=') for b in a]
```

Then i got this

> [ ' "1111"  ', ' "2222" ', ' "3333" ', ' "4444"  ']

I have tried some way to remove  outside '   ',but I still can not make it

I want to get

> ["1111","2222","3333","4444"]

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you should be managing your data in a less crazy way so that this is not necessary... You shouldn't have gotten the quotes there in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technic -1 :** Using **`strip()`:**

```
>>> a=['="1111"', '="2222"', '="3333"', '="4444"']
>>> b=[b.strip('=').strip('"') for b in a]
>>> b
['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']
```

**Technic -2 :** Using **`replace()` :**

```
>>> a=['="1111"', '="2222"', '="3333"', '="4444"']
>>> b=[b.replace("=","").replace('"',"") for b in a]
>>> b
['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']
```

Above both Technics are suitable for simple and small list. If we follow the same approach for the list containing 1000 elements, it will iterate over 1000 elements. So for avoiding, you can follow **Technic - 3**:

```
>>> a=['="1111"', '="2222"', '="3333"', '="4444"']
>>> b = ','.join(a).replace("'","").replace('"',"").replace("=","").split(",")
>>> b
['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']
```

or

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = ','.join(a)
>>> re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9,]+','',mystring).split(",")
['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip()` allows you to trim by multiple characters:

```
a = ['="1111"', '="2222"', '="3333"', '="4444"']
b = [i.strip('="') for i in a]
print(b)
```

The output:

```
['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']
```